# Unable to use Intent via button click

Tags: android, android-intent

Help me get to know how to use Intent.
Can't get to the next desired activity through this "intent" use in the code as follows

```
     public class GetIn extends Activity {
EditText editName;
EditText editPsscd;
EditText editSport;
EditText editTeam;
Button button;
final Context context = this;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_in);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editPsscd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editSport = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editTeam = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Success.class);

            intent.putExtra("Name",editName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Passcode",editPsscd.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Sports",editSport.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Team", editTeam.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Is the use of context valid here?? 
This is the "Success.java" file

```
    public class Success extends GetIn {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    TextView textName;
    TextView textSport;
    TextView textTeam;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.success);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    textName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textName.setText("Your name is "+intent.getStringExtra("Name").toString());
    textSport=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textSport.setText("Your Favourite sports is "+intent.getStringExtra("Sport").toString());
    textTeam=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textTeam.setText("Your Favourite team is "+intent.getStringExtra("Team").toString());

}
```

}

Comment: what is the problem any logcat(exception) ?

Comment: what about next activiy `Success`

Comment: No.Actually when tap on the button,it should take me to next activity called "success" here!and i don't find any exceptions or errors when i run it,but when i tap the "Done" button the app crashes showing "Unfortunately the GetIn application has stopped working".

Comment: i have used "Intent intent = getIntent();" in success file,but no help there...

Answer (score 4):

You should replace this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,Success.class);
```

With

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GetIn.this,Success.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("Name here",editName.getText().toString());
b.putString("Passcode here",editPsscd.getText().toString());
b.putString("Sports here",editSport.getText().toString());
b.putString("Team here",editTeam.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Register `Success` activity into `manifest.xml`

And into **Success Activity** get `Intent` value like

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 String Name=b.getString("Name here"); 
 String Passcode=b.getString("Passcode here");
 String Sports=b.getString("Sports here");
 String Team =b.getString("Team here");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

A `Context` as its first parameter (`this` is used because the `Activity` class is a subclass of `Context`)

also change this

```
public class Success extends GetIn
```

to

```
public class Success extends Activity
```

Comment: i also tried extending Success to Activity,but in the end its of no use!!@Dhawal Sodha Parmar

Comment: my main problem is that i am not getting into other activity after tapping "Done" button.

Comment: you have add Success in android manifest file, any errors please show logs

Comment: i have added the success activity in Android manifest file>Activity GetIn>activity Success . GetIn has intent-filters aslo but i don't know the Action or category information regarding Success,as i m new to all this.So tell me what to do now?  and BTW its showing parser-exception     @Dhawal Sodha Parmar

Comment: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
          android:name="GetIn"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_get_in" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter></activity><activity android:name="Success" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:process="@string/Done"></activity></application>